# Dataset and Select with a SmoothKernelDistribution

Tags: bugs, dataset, filtering

This question is hopefully a case of stupidity on my side, but I just don't understand why this happens. I had code that worked perfectly fine for several weeks and gives an error now on Linux and Mac. I could reduce it to a simple example.

First, we create a simple `Dataset` consisting of 2d random points and I create a kernel density estimator for the point set:

```
RandomSeed[12345];
ds = Dataset[<|"a" -> #1, "b" -> #2|> & @@@ 
    RandomVariate[
     MultinormalDistribution[{24.6, 104.19}, {{10.2, 1}, {1, 15.9}}], 
     407]];
kd = SmoothKernelDistribution[Normal[ds[All, Values]]]
```

Now I want to select some of the points that are inside the area of a certain probability which can be done with the `PDF` and a simple `Select`:

```
kernelProbability = 0.00059914;
func = PDF[kd, {#"a", #"b"}] >= kernelProbability &;
ds[Select[func] /* Length]
```

What I get is an unspecific error message `Part::partd`

> [image: graphics]

Turning the call inside out and using `Select[ds, func]` doesn't change a thing. I was debugging this by trying whether my `func` did work, and it does

```
func@Normal[ds[1]]
(* True *)
```

Here comes the crazy part, if you **now** evaluate the `Select` call again, it does work

```
ds[Select[func] /* Length]
(* 397 *)
```

I think I could trace the source of the error down, but I don't see why this happens. Does anyone have a clue? Can you reproduce this behavior?

## Update

I reported the issue and it is now filed for the Wolfram dev team: **CASE:3826715**

Comment: I can reproduce this behaviour in V11.0.1 on Win7/64.  `ds[1 /* func]` fails but `ds[1 /* func, FailureAction->None]` succeeds and causes the first expression to start working.  Neither `ClearSystemCache[]` nor ``Dataset`ResetCompileQueryCache[]`` returns the system to the broken state.  If I define `vals = Normal[ds[All, Values]]` then evaluating `kd = SmoothKernelDistribution[vals]` alone is enough to restore the broken behaviour.

Comment: I can reproduce on 10.4.1 as well.

Comment: Thank god I'm not that crazy. I may have figured out why my code worked the whole time. The example I posted is only a small part of a larger notebook. Yesterday, I was working only on that particular section without evaluating the whole notebook. It seems that at some point, I did something like `func@Normal[ds[1]]` to test stuff and therefore, the issue never appeared before. Very weird.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Short, Short Version**

A `General::stop` message will cause a dataset query to fail if some other explicitly quieted message occurs three or more times.  For example:

```
Dataset[1][Quiet[Do[Message[f::ivar, #], 2]; #, f::ivar] &]
(* 1                -- success: only two quieted f::ivar messages generated *)

Dataset[1][Quiet[Do[Message[f::ivar, #], 3]; #, f::ivar] &]
(* Failure[...]     -- third f:ivar message triggers a General::stop and failure *)
```

**Short Version**

The behaviour we see is due to an unfortunate combination of circumstances:

1. Generating the PDF of a `SmoothKernelDistribution` generates some messages which are internally suppressed using `Quiet`.
2. Distribution results are routinely cached so that the messages in question are only generated during the first evaluation.
3. `FailureAction -> "Abort"` is the default setting for `Dataset` queries and it causes queries to fail if any unexpected messages are generated.  A message is unexpected if it has not been explicitly quieted by code executed within the body of the query.
4. `PDF[...]` is generating so many `Part::partd` messages that the system issues a `General::stop` message.  Normally, a `General::stop` receives special treatment and quieted along with the messages that generated it, but the hypersensitive `FailureAction` machinery classifies it as an unexpected message and fails the query.

**Work-around**

A work-around is to turn off the special message handling from the `Dataset` query:

```
ds[Select[func] /* Length, FailureAction -> None]
(* 397 *)
```

**Is It A Bug?**

Yes, I think so.  Given that in normal circumstances `General::stop` is only generated after some other message has appeared for the third time, the bug would be corrected if `General::stop` was always presumed to be quieted by `` GeneralUtilities`MessageQuietedQ `` (see discussion below).

---

**Spelunking Report (current as of version 11.0.1)**

*... be prepared for too much complicated trivia ...*

Let's begin by finding a minimal set of steps to reproduce the behaviour:

```
d = SmoothKernelDistribution[{{1.,2.}}];

Dataset[{1., 2.}][PDF[d, #]&]
(* Failure[...] *)

PDF[d, {1., 2.}]
(* 0.390901 *)

Dataset[{1., 2.}][PDF[d, #]&]
(* 0.390901 *)

d = SmoothKernelDistribution[{{1.,2.}}];

Dataset[{1., 2.}][PDF[d, #]&]
(* Failure[...] *)
```

Notice how the bad behaviour disappears after performing a non-query evaluation and how it reappears after reassigning a newly created distribution to `d`.  *(bonus trivia: using the operator form `PDF[d]` always fails as it appears to defeat the cache)*

**PDF Evaluation Generates Messages**

By blocking the action of `Quiet`, we can observe that `PDF[d, {1., 2.}]` generates messages that would normally be quieted:

```
d = SmoothKernelDistribution[{{1.,2.}}];
Block[{Quiet}, PDF[d, {1., 2.}]]

(*
  >> Part::partd: Part specification $x[[1]] is longer than depth of object.
  >> Part::partd: Part specification $x[[2]] is longer than depth of object.
  >> Part::partd: Part specification $x[[1]] is longer than depth of object.
  >> General::stop: Further output of Part::partd will be suppressed during this calculation.

  0.390901
*)
```

... but only the first time:

```
Block[{Quiet}, PDF[d, {1., 2.}]]
(* 0.390901 *)
```

We can use an alternative technique to view considerably more details about the generated messages and their evaluation contexts:

```
d = SmoothKernelDistribution[{{1.,2.}}];
Internal`HandlerBlock[{"Message",Print[Internal`QuietStatus[]]&}, PDF[d,  {1., 2.}]]

(*
{Global->Unquiet,Off->{Part::partd},On->{},Stack->{{1458,{Part::partd},{}}},MessageList->{{Part::partd,1458}},Check->None}
{Global->Unquiet,Off->{Part::partd},On->{},Stack->{{1458,{Part::partd},{}}},MessageList->{{Part::partd,1458},{Part::partd,1458}},Check->None}
...
{Global->Unquiet,Off->{Part::partd},On->{},Stack->{{1458,{Part::partd},{}}},MessageList->{{Part::partd,1458},{Part::partd,1458},{Part::partd,1458},{General::stop,1458}},Check->None}
{Global->Unquiet,Off->{Part::partd},On->{},Stack->{{1458,{Part::partd},{}}},MessageList->{{Part::partd,1458},{Part::partd,1458},{Part::partd,1458},{General::stop,1458}},Check->None}

0.390901
*)
```

We will shortly see that the `Stack` values from `` Internal`QuietStatus `` are relevant.

**Distribution Calculations Use A Cache**

The presence of a cache is strongly hinted by the fact that the messages disappear during the first evaluation of `PDF` but reappear if we regenerate the distribution itself.  We can confirm this guess by tracing calls to `StoreDataDistributionExpression`:

```
On[Statistics`DataDistributionUtilities`StoreDataDistributionExpression]

System`Dump`DeactivateReadProtected[{DataDistribution, PDF}
, Print["#### define"]; d = SmoothKernelDistribution[{{1.,2.}}]
; Print["#### pdf1"];   PDF[d,{1.,2.}]
; Print["#### pdf2"];   PDF[d,{1.,2.}]
]

Off[]

(* Output:
#### define
   ... messages showing calls to StoreDataDistributionExpression ...
#### pdf1
   ... messages showing more calls to StoreDataDistributionExpression ...
#### pdf2
   ... no messages! ...
*)
```

Observe how the initial distribution generation tucked some values into a cache, as did the first PDF evaluation.  But the second PDF evaluation did not store into the cache at all.

**FailureAction Treats Messages As Query Failure**

Now, we can move on to `FailureAction` in dataset queries.  As noted earlier, the default action is to cause a query to fail should any messages be generated:

```
Dataset[1][(Message[f::ivar, #]; #) &]
(* Failure[...] *)
```

But quieted messages do not (normally) cause failure:

```
Dataset[1][Quiet[Message[f::ivar, #]; #] &]
(* 1 *)
```

We can also turn off the failure processing:

```
Dataset[1][(Message[f::ivar, #]; #) &, FailureAction -> None]
(* 
    >> f: 1 is not a valid variable
    1
*)
```

**Unexpected Messages Trigger FailureAction**

But if the previous example shows that quieted messages do not trigger `FailureAction`, what is so special about the quieted messages we observed for this:

```
d = SmoothKernelDistribution[{{1.,2.}}];
Dataset[{1., 2.}][PDF[d, #]&]
(* Failure[...] *)
```

To find the answer, we need to closely inspect a voluminous trace of the evaluation (not reproduced here).  Deep in the bowels of that trace, we find that the relevant functions are:

```
Needs["GeneralUtilities`"]
{ EvaluateChecked, GeneralUtilities`Failure`PackagePrivate`CheckedHandler
, MessageStackID, MessageQuietedQ
} // Scan[PrintDefinitionsLocal]
```

In short, `EvaluateChecked` begins by setting up an environment which will catch and handle any messages.  `MessageStackID` is used to identify the outermost stack boundary of that environment.  Should a message appear, `CheckedHandler` will inspect the message to determine if it should be ignored.  Any message that is not `MessageQuietedQ` will cause a failure.  `MessageQuietedQ` uses the `` Internal`QuietStatus[] `` output we saw earlier to see if the message has been explicitly quieted by code within the bounded stack environment.

**Putting It All Together**

In the case at hand, `PDF[...]` explicitly quiets the message `Part::partd`.  But is does not explicitly quiet `General::stop`.

And so, to finally reach the end of our long-winded shaggy dog story... it is the `General::stop` message that causes the query to fail.  That message only appears the first time the PDF function is generated because the function is cached on subsequent attempts.

Comment: And it explains perfectly, why I haven't noticed this earlier. I was of course inspecting the PDF and creating some density plots where I evaluated the PDF. Thanks for this answer.

Comment: Hell of a shaggy dog indeed. +1!

Comment: @halirutan My pleasure -- I was intrigued by this strangeness of this one.  Thanks for the bounty.

Answer (score 4):

## Workaround with Efficiency Improvement

Another approach, which also makes your code more efficient, is to create the [`PDF`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PDF.html) of the [`SmoothKernelDistribution`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SmoothKernelDistribution.html) only once.

When written as

```
func = PDF[kd, {#"a", #"b"}] >= kernelProbability &;
ds[Select[func] /* Length]
```

`kd` is resolved into its PDF for each row in the [`Dataset`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dataset.html) because, as [`Attributes`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Attributes.html) tells us, [`Function`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Function.html) has attribute [`HoldAll`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HoldAll.html).  Here it is not too complicated for `PDF` to resolve `kd` into its PDF so you don't really notice this.

However, we can resolve the PDF of `kd` only once and then evaluate it repeatedly in the [`Query`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Query.html).

```
ClearAll[x, y];
pdf[x_, y_] = PDF[kd, {x, y}];
func1 = pdf[#"a", #"b"] >= kernelProbability &;
ds[Select[func1] /* Length]
```

`pdf` is [`Set`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Set.html) to the resolved PDF of `kd` outside of the [`Select`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Select.html). Now for each row the resolved PDF (`pdf`) is evaluated. The overhead of resolving it for each row is removed. This not only makes your code more efficient but bypasses the bug as well.

In general be aware of the *cost* of your expression when doing row-by-row evaluations.

Hope this helps.